# ASP.NET Core SignalR connection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

I'm using ASP.NET Core SignalR to send real-time data. I have written a runtime service that collects client's data to the hub and then distributes it from the hub to another client. But is suffering from data stagnation in the hub's queue. That is, when the client connects to the hub to get data, it sometimes loses data for 1,2 minutes, then 40.50 messages continuously shoot down from the hub while their data is very stable without such loss of connection. Have any of you encountered this situation?

Comment: Do you face any connection fail during the data lose?

Comment: I have written events that automatically connect when the connection is lost. See in the connection history, the client did not interrupt the connection. I use login JWT signalr , timeout period is 3 days. as far as i track this problem happens every 2-3 days. is it because of the JWT timeout needing to re-login?